# concordance of characters occurring in a string (Java)

Tags: java

Can any body help me to slove this:

Write a program which creates a concordance of characters occurring in a string (i.e., which characters occur where in a string). Read the string from the command line.
Running the program:

> java Concordance Hello World

{d=[9], o=[4, 6], r=[7], W=[5], H=[0], l=[2, 3, 8], e=[1]}

I Try this code:

```
package q4;

public class Q4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        //        String string = input.nextLine();
        //        indexOfChar(string);
        indexOfChar("hello");
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("empty-statement")
    public static void indexOfChar(String string) {
        int counter;
        counter = 0;
        String letter;
        int[] letterCounter = new int[26];
        letter = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

        for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
            counter = 0;
            letterCounter[letter.indexOf(string.charAt(i))]++;
        }

        counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < letterCounter.length; i++) {
            if (letterCounter[i] != 0) {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        String s = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
            // char ch=name.charAt(i);
            if (letterCounter[letter.indexOf(string.charAt(i))] != 0) {
                System.out.print(string.charAt(i) + "=[");
            }
            for (int j = i; j < string.length(); j++) {
                if (string.charAt(i) == string.charAt(j)) {
                    System.out.print(j + ",");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("]");
        }
        //System.out.println(counter);
    }
}
```

Comment: You try this code. And what happens? What's your question?

Comment: this smells like homework assignment to me. WHat is the actual problem you are encountering? don't just say "here's my problem fix it" but tell us what you specifically need help wiht

Comment: Right this is a homework, but what the problem in request a help I try and hava a problem, why cannot ask an expert like you for help in specific area not write a complete program :)

Thank you.

Comment: @MohammedSatari what is the order of characters printed in output ? i don't see it either in ascending or descending or based on some index ? e.g. why d is printed first ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) where you map each character to its set of occurences. You can use a set over a list because each position is unique in a string.

```
class Test{

    private static Map<Character, Set<Integer>> characterConcordance(final String input) {

        Map<Character, Set<Integer>> concordance = new HashMap<Character, Set<Integer>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            char charAt = input.charAt(i);
            if (charAt == ' ') {
                continue; // ignore spaces
            }
            Set<Integer> set= concordance.get(charAt);
            if (set == null) {
                set= new HashSet<Integer>();
            }
            set.add(i + 1); // use i for 0-indexed, or (i+1) for 1-indexed positions
            concordance.put(charAt, set);
        }

        return concordance;
   }

   public static void main(final String[] args) {

       System.out.println(Test.characterConcordance("Java is cool!!"));
    //prints {v=[3], !=[13, 14], s=[7], c=[9], a=[2, 4], o=[10, 11], l=[12], J=[1], i=[6]}
   }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I solve the problem throug:

```
package q4;

import java.util.*;
public class Q4{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = input.nextLine();

        char []data=str.toCharArray();
        Set s = new HashSet();
        for(int i=0; i<data.length; i++){
            s.add(data[i]);
        }
        Object[] s1 = s.toArray();

        System.out.print("{ ");
        for(int i=0; i<s.size(); i++){
            System.out.print(s.toArray()[i]+"=");
            Collection t = new ArrayList();
            char c=(Character) s1[i];
            for(int j=0;j<data.length; j++){
                if(c==data[j]){
                    t.add(j);
                }
            }
            System.out.print(t+ ", ");

        }
        System.out.print("}");

    }
}
```